# What should the description for the "arguments" tag be?

Tags: discussion, tags

[arguments](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arguments) doesn't have a description, and the tag could be used for different purposes (e.g. function arguments). To avoid this, the tag should have a description.

What should its description be?
If the tag is used just for view arguments, should not it be renamed [views-arguments](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-arguments)?